# Can I Use Functions Returning T/F in Propositional/First-Order Logic?

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am writing my (first) paper...

I need to explain about my algorithm.

I think it is good to define some functions/statements.

It is a huge pain to clearly explain them in words.

But I am not that familiar with mathematics so I am not sure if I can use functions I defined in Propositional/First-Order logic statements.

$$P\text{.isEqualTo}(P')=
\begin{cases}
\text{false,} & |P|\neq|P'|\\
\overset{|P|}{\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}}\left(P_i={P_i'} \right),& \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

$$P\text{.isMoreGeneralThan}(P')=
\begin{cases}
\text{false,} & |P|\neq|P'|\\
\text{false,}& \overset{|P|}{\sum\limits_{i=1}}\left[P_i\neq P_i'\right]=0 \\
\overset{|P|}{\bigwedge\limits_{i=1}}\left(P_i={P_i'} \space\space\lor\space{}_{\text{-}}\right),& \text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

I defined 'pattern equality' and 'pattern generality.' Can I use them in the logical statements:

$$P\text{.isMatchedBy}(P')\impliedby P.\text{isEqualTo}(P')\lor P.\text{isMoreGreaterThan}(P')$$

$$P\text{.isParentOf}(P')\impliedby P.\text{isMoreGeneralThan}\land \left(\sum_{i=1}^{|P|}\left[P_i \neq P_i'\right]=1\right)$$

If possible, can I also wrtie a first order logic statement using quantifier like:

$$P\text{.isAddable()}\impliedby \exists P'(P'\text{.isParentOf}(P)\land P'\text{.isExpendable}())$$

where 'expandability' is defined as:

$$\text{P.isExpendable}()=
\begin{cases}
\text{True} & P\text{.SP}-\max\limits_{p\in\left\{P'|P'\text{.isParentOf(P)}\right\}}p\text{.SP}\gt\eta\\
\text{False}, & \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Ah, I am in total confusion. Please save me. Thank you geniuses!

Comment: So what is your question?  Is it to see if your defined functions and expressions capture the intended meaning?  And if so, what *is* their intended meaning?  From your names I can *sort of* figure out the intent, but not always ...

Comment: @Bram28 If you cannot figure it out, sorry for bad definitions... What I wanted to know is if functions like those can be used in first order logic statements...? I somehow think I've never used summation or numbers in first order logic statements.

Comment: @Bram28 These functions are just to explain my algorithm. Maybe I can also use them in my pseudocode?

Comment: Next time use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting images. I know it's tedious but it will prepare you to write math papers in the future.

Comment: In regard to the title question, propositions are *normally* expressed with a syntax resembling that of a truth-valued function. Some forms of logic even make that explicit, defining a predicate on a type $T$ as an element of type $T \to \mathrm{Bool}$. (where $\mathrm{Bool}$ stands for the type of truth values)

Comment: "Member functions", however, are very unusual to see in syntax of formal logics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These expressions are certainly not part of the standard language of First-order logic (FOL). As you already suspected, summations and programming constructions like $P.isEqualTo(P')$ are not part of FOL. Now, if this is just pseudocode to convey certain ideas, then it should be fine though. Also, if you really need it to be in FOL, you can do so with some additional effort. For example,

$P.isMatchedby(P') \Leftarrow P.isEqualTo(P') \lor P.isMoreGreaterThan(P')$

Can be put into FOL like so:

$\forall x \forall y ((Equals(x,y) \lor GreaterThan(x,y)) \rightarrow MatchedBy(x,y))$

For a more complicated example, you can express the $P.isEqualTo(P')$ with something like:

$\forall x \forall y (Equals(x,y) \leftrightarrow (size(x) = size(y) \land \forall z ((1 \le z \land z \le size(x)) \rightarrow ent(x,z) = ent(y,z))))$

where $size(x)$ is a function symbol that expresses the function $|P|$, and where $ent(x,z)$ denotes $P_i$ assuming $x$ denotes some object $P$ and $z$ some number $i$. Note that you may need to add some axioms to deal with $1$ and $\le$ if you were to use this in practice.

But again, if you goal is to simply convey some idea, then your notation has plenty of rigor to be precise, and is probably more readable than a full FOL epression.

Comment: I have a question. Can't I define a predicate P(x) = x > 3 ? Then why can I define a predicate with a case function? Ah, so confusing...

Comment: Yes, you can use $x > 3$ as a predicate statement. Predicates and functions are  not the same though, e.g > is a predicate, not a function. But you can define relations with cases.

Comment: Ah! Not a function... Actually, if i don't need P.isAddable()⟸∃P′(P′.isParentOf(P)∧P′.isExpendable()), which there should be at least one P′... I do not really want to use FOL. Can I express at least one without using FOL?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi Just use $\exists$. That is, I would use the useful parts from logic and combine them with other mathematical/computational notation. Again, if this is just to describe some ideas, it is ok, to use a mix of different notations ... It's done in mathematics all the time. in fact, you will still be using English words and phrases, and you can use diagrams too. look at all these different 'languages' as a *means* to get your ideas across ... The notation is not the *end*.